# Most Effective way to search a value in a list of values [ORACLE SQL]

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I am trying to find a value in a list of values using SQL so I was trying to used something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_EXAMPLE WHERE FIELD_EXAMPLE IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', ...)
```

The list of values that I am searching has about 84k elements so I cannot use this type of query because I'll get an error since the list is so large.

Is there an effective way of performing this type of query even when searching on a very large list?

The solution I implemented was breaking the query into simpler queries, so I ended up with something like this:

```
select * from table_example where field_example = '1';
select * from table_example where field_example = '2';
select * from table_example where field_example = '3';
select * from table_example where field_example = '4';
select * from table_example where field_example = '5';
```

and so on...

Comment: Load the list into a table and use SQL operations such as `JOIN`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is right; that is about the only reasonable way to do this.  Just so you know, the `IN(` clause is limited to 256 elements, so unless you nest a whole bunch of them, not an option.  If your 84,000 elements are in a flat file that is on the same server as your Oracle database, and it is in a reasonable format such as CSV, or fixed length, etc. you might be able to use External Tables to treat it as if were a database table and join to it.  If so, [edit] your question and show some sample lines from that file. Also add a version tag such as [oracle12c] for your version.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem in two ways:

- load all 84k searched data in a table and use that table with a join to the TABLE_EXAMPLE. In this case it will be useful to add also an identifier of the search so that you can use this table with concurrent queries searching different values
- split your 84k records in a smaller set that can be handled by your query and use the original `SELECT * FROM TABLE_EXAMPLE WHERE FIELD_EXAMPLE IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', ...)` limited to a reasonable number of searched values

**Load searched data in a table**

Here is a description of all the steps for the solution using a SEARCHED_DATA table.

- Create a table SEARCHED_DATA with the columns FIELD_EXAMPLE and SEARCH_ID.
- Create a unique ID to be used in the field SEARCH_ID
- Add the 84k records in the SEARCHED_DATA all with the same SEARCH_ID generated before
- Select with an inner join between the two tables: `SELECT T.* FROM TABLE_EXAMPLE T INNER JOIN SEARCHED_DATA S ON T.FIELD_EXAMPLE = S.FIELD_EXAMPLE and S.SEARCH_ID = 'CREATEDID'
- Delete the records from SEARCHED_DATA with the SEARCH_ID once you retrieved all the data that you need